# Python: Passing an instance to a nested function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.base = x
        self.core = y

    def addBaseCore(self, initial):
        def addBase(z):   # vs. def addBase(self, z)
            return z + self.base
        initial += self.core
        # vs. Do we pass self to the nested function? e.g. addBase(self, z)
        return addBase(initial)
```

I am new to Python and I am curious how/why is it possible to access the attributes of an instance within a nested function without explicitly passing the instance to the nested function (as shown above)?

The inner method is not exactly an instance method neither does it receive the instance as an argument. How is the inner method still able to access the attributes of the instance?

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to pass `self` into the nested function that's defined inside your member function.

Here's an example using your code.

```py
a = A(10, 20)
print(a.addBaseCore(30))
```

Output

```
60
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware that the code snippet works as originally intended. But I am curious why does it work? How does the inner function have access to the instance when it is not a) an instance method b) does not receive the instance in the arguments.

Comment: The inner function shares context with the outer function. In this case, the outer function is a member function.